# Magic Quotes GPC error installing Joomla 3.2 - need to disable

Tags: php, joomla

I'm currently trying to install Joomla 3.2 on my godaddy account but having issues installing it because Magic Quotes GPC is not Off.

I have tried a combination of the following:

Php.ini (installed in the root and installation folder)
Php5.ini (installed in the root and installation folder)

first

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.s
display_errors = Off
error_reporting = Off
```

second

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
php_flag magic_quotes_sybase off
```

does anyone know how i can get round this or how to turn it off for joomla?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8383/what-is-magic-quotes

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4303840

Comment: @neil that does not fix the issue, as I have already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Create php.ini file with the following lines.

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

Copy to the Installation subfolder of your site.

Let me know if it fixes your problem.

Comment: hi Danny, sorry but this doesnt work? anything else i can try?

Comment: _anything else i can try?_ Switch to a host that doesn't force you to use software that was deprecated six years ago. :)

Comment: Is it not possible to install a recent joomla version?

Comment: Here you can see a solution for shared hosting: godaddy and joomla 3.x
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=707&t=768674#p3074649 , i hope this will helps you ;) => Please do not forget to RESTART your PHP server after modifying your ini file(s)

Comment: i have already came across that article and it doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: I suppose you have to contact godaddy, there it's an older version from Joomla and recent answers to this question remains unsolved ...
I'm sorry that i could not help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

These lines should work in a .htaccess file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime off
php_flag magic_quotes_sybase off
```

They will definitely not work in a php.ini.

Comment: i have deleted the .yxy of the end of the file and inserted the 3 lines and then put the file in the root but still no luck

Comment: the file name is .htaccess, not sure what you've entitled it though. In any  case, GoDaddy support should really be able to solve this for you at the very least. (or switch to a decent host!)

Comment: I will have a look, I logged a support ticket with go daddy anyway yesterday so hopefully they can fix it.